# Out of memory while adding documents to a Firebird BLOB field with Delphi

Tags: delphi, blob, streaming, firebird

The following code will add 3000 to 4000 documents of various sizes to a Firebird Blob field before running out of memory. I believe I have freed the streams I create, but I may not be doing it correctly. Streams are a new tool in my toolbox. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
procedure TfrmMigration.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DocFile: string;
  Blob: TStream;
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  with DM.qImageList do
  begin
    close;
    SQL.Text := ImgListSQL;
    open;
    First;

    while not eof do
    begin
      { Ignore if previously done.}
      if (FieldByName('Document_Files').IsNull) then
      begin
        DocFile := Trim(gsDocumentPath + '\' + FieldByName('ImageName').asString);
        if FileExists(DocFile) then
        begin
          edit;
          Blob := CreateBlobStream(FieldByName('Document_Files'), bmWrite);
          try
            Blob.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
            fs := TFileStream.Create(DocFile, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
            try
              Blob.CopyFrom(fs, fs.Size);
            finally
              fs.free;
            end;
          finally
            Blob.free;
          end;
          post;
        end;
      end;
      next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The code you have shown is fine. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: There's no problem with this code (other than inconsistent capitalization and the use of `with`). You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The problem with this code is that TIBBlobStream load into memory whole content before sending it into database. And TIBDataSet also caches in memory whole result set. IBX (and DB VCL as whole) is crap.

Comment: That's only logical if all the streams are freed before `Post()` is executed - isn't there a way to commit the database changes and **with that** the streams are read/wrote? Otherwise it's all pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for pitching in. You were correct. There was nothing actually wrong with my code.

I solved the memory depletion issue by turning off CacheBlobs in my query component. I'm using IBDAC, and all I needed to do was set that property to False. That allowed me to copy 107,389 documents into the database in a little over one hour on a fairly slow Windows 11 machine (running the app in the IDE). It seems I had been putting data into cache faster than it was being removed.

Again, thank you for all your comments.